# Multi-dimensional array is entirely (aside the first value) set to appended value

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, append

I'm making a function to find all the combinations for a given set of options. When I append a combination as a list to the main list of total combinations (the combinations are indexes, to be taken from the list of options later), all of the existing lists are changed to the list I just appended, apart from the first.

```
def allCombos(opts):
    limit = len(opts) - 1
    combos = []
    for n in range(1, 3):
        combo = [0] * n
        print(combo) # going to remove this
        goal = [limit] * n
        pointer = 0
        overflowed = False
        while True:
            if combo[pointer] == limit:
                pointer += 1
                overflowed = True
            else:
                if overflowed:
                    combo[pointer] += 1
                    for i in range(pointer):
                        combo[i] = 0
                    pointer = 0
                    combos.append(combo)
                    print(combo) # I will change this
                else:
                    combo[pointer] += 1
                    combos.append(combo)
                    print(combo) # and this
            if combo == goal:
                break

allCombos(["foo", "bar"])
```

outputs

```
[0]
[1]
[0, 0]
[1, 0]
[0, 1]
[1, 1]
```

whereas

```
def allCombos(opts):
    limit = len(opts) - 1
    combos = []
    for n in range(1, 3):
        combo = [0] * n
        goal = [limit] * n
        pointer = 0
        overflowed = False
        while True:
            if combo[pointer] == limit:
                pointer += 1
                overflowed = True
            else:
                if overflowed:
                    combo[pointer] += 1
                    for i in range(pointer):
                        combo[i] = 0
                    pointer = 0
                    combos.append(combo)
                    print(combos) # changed
                else:
                    combo[pointer] += 1
                    combos.append(combo)
                    print(combos) # changed
            if combo == goal:
                break
    print("\n" + str(combos)) #added

allCombos(["foo", "bar"])
```

outputs

```
[[1]]
[[1], [1, 0]]
[[1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]

[[1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
```

This seems odd, as the only specified modifications of `combos` seems to be the appending.

I've looked for other questions with similar issues, but I couldn't find any.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't see where you have gone wrong. The output of the code matches my understanding of your code.  I suspect that `itertools.combinations` might do what you want: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're appending several references to `combo` to `combos`.  When you change `combo`, those references all point to the modified list.  Compare to this simple example:

```
>>> x=[1,2]
>>> y=[]
>>> y.append(x)
>>> y.append(x)
>>> y
[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
>>> x[0]+=1
>>> y
[[2, 2], [2, 2]]
>>>
```

Notice that `combo` originally starts out as [0], but you never see that in the output. That's because it's been changed to [1].  When you get to the top of the loop, you set `combo` to [0,0].  Why doesn't that affect `combos`?  Because you've set `combo` to a new value.  The reference in `combos` points to a different object than the newly-created combo.  Now you start changing `combo` in place, and appending it to the list.  You just get multiple copies of the same thing.

If this isn't clear, try setting the limit to 3 instead of 2.  Can you predict what the output will be?

I think that Gary van der Merwe made a good suggestion, but I believe he's thinking of `itertools.product`, not `itertools.combinations`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't know that I was appending references.

Comment: Glad to help.  Python is a reference-oriented language.  That's the hardest thing to get used to if you're coming from a value oriented language like C++.  Even `x=y` means different things in the two languages!